# How to move a table from one database to another while keeping references in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a table `A` in `database1` (.accdb file)
Various tables and queries in `database1` reference table `A`.

I want to move table `A` to `database2` but I don't want to "break" `database1`. 
I want `database1` to keep the references but point at the new location in `database2`.

How to I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a link to database_2 in database_1 (External Data)

Comment: Should I first click and drag the table into database 2, then delete table in database 1, then create a link to database_2.table? Will I not loose the references? 
I get: "Deleting this object will remove it from all groups"

Comment: Back up everything first. A group is simply a display item in the database window (sidebar). Deleting will remove tables from relationships. Access includes a wizard for splitting databases.

Comment: Thanks Remou for the input.
I splitted the database (Dtabase Tools -> Move data -> Access Database) but that moved ALL the tables into another "backend" database. I wanted to move just one of the tables. 
But it is kind of nice, now I can have all the tables hidden and have multiple "specialized" front ends that interfaces them and create the logic between the tables... hmmm.

Comment: It is a standard design, and good practice to have a backend and a frontend.

Comment: Thanks @Remou However I still want to "take out" table A from backend1. I want backend1 to reference to table A in backend2. 

The reason is that I want each "application" to have its own backend, to make the borders between the apps more clear.

Comment: Copy the table to db2, delete it from db1 and then use External Data to link it back to db1. Backup everything first.

Comment: @Remou "Cant delete until relationships to other tables have been deleted", Thanks

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, relationships have to go. You should get a message asking whether you want to delete the relationship.